# Querying across schemas in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I am using Postgres and I have multiple schemas (i.e. S1 and S2).  I would like to run a query that uses tables in S1 and S2. is it possible to do something like this:

```
select * from S1.table1, S2.table2
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: That will give you a `CROSS JOIN` which might return a **huge** dataset!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. And the syntax is exactly how you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, I think that the correct query is:

```
select * from S1.table1
UNION ALL
select * from S2.table2
```

Comment: The OP was not very specific about what he wanted to do with the data (just talked about a query that uses both tables). Depending on his actual goal, the correct solution could be what he said, what you said, or something else entirely ("Select * from s1.table1 join s2.table2 on...." or "select * from s1.table1 where fieldXYZ not in (select fieldABC from s2.table2)"). The best way to answer the question is probably to interpret it as asking if prepending table names with corresponding schema names and a dot is the right way to reference tables across schemas, to which the answer is simply yes